# Что не так с циклом for (cmd)?

Tags: cmd, for

Начинаю работу с cmd и сразу же не могу выполнить первое же задание из туториала - создать цикл по инструкции (хотя копирую слово в слово)

```
for %%i in (1,1,4) do (echo a)
```

Оно выдаёт

> Непредвиденное появление: %%i.

Все другие циклы тоже не работают. Пробовал заключать в кавычки. Не работает. Может, проблема в самом cmd? Какие вообще есть варианты?
(Это консоль, а не bat, если что)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверил - работает, на всякий случай проверил с `%i`,чтобы ошибку вызвать

```
PS C:\Users\Fireman> d:
PS D:\> .\test.cmd

D:\>for %i in (1 1 4) do (echo a )

D:\>(echo a )
a

D:\>(echo a )
a

D:\>(echo a )
a
PS D:\> .\test.cmd
Непредвиденное появление: i.

D:\>for i in (1,1,4) do (echo a)
PS D:\>
```

Попробуйте еще раз код скопировать/написать в отдельном .cmd и еще раз запустить

P.S.

в самой командной строке работает

```
for %i in (1, 2, 3) do echo %i
```

в PowerShell не работает - но это другая история :)

Comment: Спасибо, в .cmd работает, не работает именно в командной строке одной командой, а нужно именно так

Comment: @Ivan, `for %i in (1, 2, 3) do echo %i` заработало в самой командной строке

Comment: То есть в командной строке использовать нужно %i, а не %%i?

Comment: @Ivan, получается, что так (можно набрать еще help for и посмотреть примеры)

Comment: Спасибо, а то я запутался